# share allocated memory buffer between c++ dynamic library and main C program

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, dynamic-library, socketserver

For work with C based socket server framework, we need to transfer data between socket server thread of C-based program and C++ based DLL.
Operation system MacOs.

Inside DLL everything works fine and we are able to manage OCR core and DB.
Inside of the socket server, everything works fine and it is mature few years tested ESP framework
[embedthis.com/esp/](https://embedthis.com/esp/)

With  help of Stackoverflow community we have developed the working solution.
The code which is working right now for transfer allocated buffer of memory from DLL to main program is:

```
//in library header
typedef
    struct pageRecord{
        char *data;
    }pageRec;

// in library function
extern "C"{
EXPORT
    pageRec helloVarStr(void) {
        //c++ content
        string stData="www ....";
        pageRec rec;
        rec.data=(char*)calloc(stData.size()+1,1);
        memcpy(rec.data,&stData[0],stData.size());
        return rec;
    }
}
//in socket server thread
       pageRec c=helloVarStr();
       printf("%s",c.data);
```

This code work fine and used pointer inside structure.
But if we will try to use just pointer itself we have memory error in C program

This code execution rise memory error:

```
 EXPORT
    const char* helloVarStr() {
        //c++ content
        char *str=(char*)calloc(stData.size()+1, 1);
        string stData="www....";
        memcpy(str,(char*)&stData[0],stData.size());
        return str;
    }
//in C language ESP socket server 
       char *report=helloVarStr(&report);  
       printf("%s",report);  //!// memory error
```

We are not able to use a direct pointer on allocated buffer as function return from library function.
This problem exists in both static and dynamic linking.

Why we can use pointer in structure as library function return, but not the pointer itself?
Does it mean DLL used another memory address space which we can not access directly?

This solution need for 6Tb, 1 request per second socket server site.

Comment: There is no need to specially "transfer" anything. It's a regular plain copy. The address space is common. Being in the "DLL" (there's no such thing on Mac OS X by the way) or in the "main program" is irrelevant. You just forgot that C style strings are null terminated. Also, `char *report=helloVarStr(&report);` makes no sense, is this a typo?

Comment: `char** report; *report` is UB as `report` is not initialised!

Comment: There's no need for casting arguments to `memcpy`: 1. &s[0] *is* already of that type (`std::` string provided) 2. `memcpy` accepts `void*` and `void const*` anyway...

Comment: @ n.m. char **report; *report=helloVarStr(&report); This is a way to initialise pointer by pointer address. After that report it is pointer on pointer. (The same as in two dimensional array. ). std::c_str() provided NUL-terminated string. Problem is library and program de-facto not share the same memory space. Of course at first we checked direct approach and try to return pointer to allocated buffer from library function.

Comment: There is no function you have posted rhat both takes an address of a pointer and returns a pointer. `void helloVarStr(char **report)` does not return anything, and `const char* helloVarStr()` doesn't take any arguments. Either way to assign a value to `report` is OK, doing both at the same time is useless and redundant (though harmless).

Comment: @Aconcagua «char** report; *report is UB as report is not initialised! » Actually it is the same declaration as two dimensional array. char **report; is a way to declare array of pointers. *report=malloc(n); in that moment we initialise the first row of this array. In every main(int argc, char *argv[]){} used the same approach. char** report; declare only one pointer on pointer, in case we will be need a few of the rows it will be char* report[n];

Comment: There is no std::c_str(). std::string::c_str does return a null-terminated string but the null terminator is not included in the size. You need to allocate and copy size+1 characters.

Comment: @ n.m.  You are right. const char* helloVarStr(){} not need argument because we need return memory buffer from library.

Comment: @n.m. Ok. you are right about c_str(). But any attempt to get one byte from this pointer give us a memory error. So printf ("%c", report[0]); give us the same memory error. calloc(stData.size()+1,1); and report[stData.size()]=0; also have no effect.

Comment: @n.m. Not sure understand you correctly -« Either way to assign a value to report is OK, doing both at the same time is useless and redundant (though harmless).» This is two different functions. One return a pointer and another init a pointer by address which it received as argument.

Comment: In C, to declare a function that takes no arguments, use `(void)` rather than `()`.

Comment: @n.m. Also work fine if we sent structure from program by function argument and init structure member pointer inside the library function. Look like pointer or structure as function argument compile another way than pointer which library return. Will try return structure from function.

Comment: The two functions are OK. `char *report=helloVarStr(&report);` fits neither of the two, and it would be redundant if the third function that does both things existed.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code, apart from the things I have pointed out. The error could be anywhere. So you need to post a [mcve]. Otherwise it's all idle speculations.

Comment: No wait, there's one more thing, `stData="www..."` can change the size of the string, so you need to allocate and immediately copy without any manipulations in between.

Comment: @dharmabook.ru `char**` per se is just a pointer to another pointer. This other pointer *could* be the address of an array - but not necessarily. Still, as long as you haven't assigned anything to your pointer to pointer, you cannot dereference it! Counterexample: `char* p; char** pp = &p; *pp = malloc(...);` Now you actually assigned a value to `p` (indirectly via `pp`). Main difference, though, is that `pp` *is* initialised, while your `report` was not! Array variant you mentioned: `char* p[n]; pp = p;` (note the missing address-of operator) – but again, `pp` is initialised!

Comment: Simpler example, replacing char* with int: `int* n; *n = 7;` As long as `n` hasn't been assigned the address of an `int`, this is UB. If you want to do `**p`, you need to have initialised `*p`, true, but `p` itself *as well* (and before `*p`)!

Comment: Dear @Aconcagua «char** per se is just a pointer to another pointer. Still, as long as you haven't assigned anything to your pointer to pointer, you cannot dereference it» Yes you are right.  correct code will be    
    int c=7;
    int **n;
    int *d=&c;
    n = &d;
    printf("%d",**n);

Comment: Dear @Aconcagua you are right.  In our code we can not use *report directly, it is need initialise it as pointer first.

Comment: There are a number of errors in the code as it currently stands. Tough to tell which are typos and which we should be concerned with. (For example, declaring `static *data` as a pointer to *nothing?* is probably a typo, but what about using `report = &data` instead of `*report = data`?) To get reasonable help, you should provide code that is complete and correct enough to be compiled, although a [mcve] would be even better.

Comment: Dear @JaMiT for now we can not extract this problem as example code for simple reason it is worked in thread of socket server dynamic library.  But we very appreciate all consideration and advice from community. We already make problem solution much better. See update in main code.

Comment: @dharmabook.ru If I understand what you are saying, you are unable to provide code that is clean enough to feed to a compiler. Not even a clean function definition (not necessarily a complete program). OK, I guess. In return, I am unable to provide help. Maybe someone else can.

Comment: A [mcve] is **required**, full stop. We cannot guess problems in code we don't see. We're engineers, not fortune tellers.